# passing html id to php/mysql, receiving 'cannot read property __e3_ of undefined'

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, google-maps

I'm making a Google Map that will pull information from a database and output xml to be interpreted into markers on the map. I want to pass the clicked elements id into the PHP to filter the database results. When the function is executed, I get an error stating "cannot read property '_*e3*' of undefined".  Everything works fine when I get rid of the variable and directly enter a type into the code.

relevant jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.map_item').toggle(
            function() {
                var itemid = this.id;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    //php script takes info from database, outputs xml
                    url:'SQL.php',
                    //pass var to the php to select only items matching this id
                    data: 'variable1=' + itemid,
                    success: function(data) {
```

relevant PHP from file SQL.php

```
$ajax_var = $_POST['variable1'];
$query = 'SELECT * FROM location WHERE Type="' . $ajax_var . '"';
$result = mysql_query($query); //sqlsrv_query
header('Content-type: text/xml'); 

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){   
// ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE  
$node = $dom->createElement('marker');  
$newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
$newnode->setAttribute("dirtType",$row['dirtType']);
$newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);  
$newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);  
 } 

 echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: Very nice [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com)... mind if someone totally pwns your server?

Comment: @MarcB Wow thanks for pointing that out.  Since it's passing an id tag, theoretically would all someone need to do while viewing the page is to open the source and change that items id tag to something like "&#34; DROP TABLE table_name" to delete the table, as the PHP would execute that new id tag as a SQL request?

Comment: Just put a (int)$ajax_var there, that is going to help with that injection.

Comment: @flapjacks: thankfully, not quite that easy. php's mysql driver doesn't allow multiple queries in a single query() call, but still.. there's plenty of other types of attacks that don't require a simple drop table and can still do vast amounts of damage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the data should be sent in a different way, like this:

```
data: {
   "variable1": itemId
}
```